# Limit Pagination pages in PhP

Tags: php, pagination

I have a hash database on my own site, and I wanted to paginate (because 210.000hashes won't load easily without slowing down the site)

now I have paginated my stuff, but I get about 21.000 pages
how can I limit this to about 100pages???

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hashes";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
echo "<a href='?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
```

Please don't mind the crappy way I made it, I just want it to work, not look pretty :)

Comment: Use LIMIT clause for SELECT query.

Answer (score 2):

**Pagination in php**

> Limit the number of items per page by

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $page=$_GET['page'];
else 
    $page=1;

$max_results=6;
$from=( ($page * $max_results) - $max_results);
```

> in this i limit 6(`$max_results=6;`) items per page **you can change
>    according to your need**
>
> Use the query to limit the results

```
$search=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hashes` LIMIT $from,$max_results"); 
$total_results=mysql_result(mysql_query("select count(*) as num from `hashes`"),0);
while($r=mysql_fetch_object($search))
{//your code}
```

> Pagination concept to provide links for pages

```
$total_pages=ceil($total_results/$max_results);
if($total_results>$max_results)
{
if($page>1)
{
    $prev=($page-1);
    echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$prev\" style='text-decoration:none'>&nbsp;<< Previous&nbsp;</a>";
}
for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++)
{
    if($page==$i)
    {
        echo $i."";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$i\" style='text-decoration:none'>&nbsp;$i&nbsp;</a>";
    }
}
if($page<$total_pages)
{
    $next=($page+1);
    echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$next\" style='text-decoration:none'>&nbsp;Next>></a>";
}
}
```

Comment: I've already limited the amount of items it will display per page.

and I've copy-pasted the 2nd codesample you provided, but now the pagination is defectish (it won't showup the numbers anymore)

Comment: Are you telling number  are not displaying for pagination link.?? use this `echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=$i\" style='text-decoration:none'> $i </a></li>";`

Comment: I'm currently trying to just toy around and see if I can get any progress, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Consider using LIMIT clause in sql query - it will be efficient and will solve your problem

Comment: I limited the amount of hashes it shows per page to 100, but since I have alot of hashes (210.000+) this results 2100pages :\

[view site](https://finlaydag33k.nl/hashdb)

Comment: So what do you want us to do? 210.000 / 100 = 2100 pages. If you were to up the pagesize to 500, you'd get 2100/5 = 420 pages. We can't make your hashes disappear.

Comment: I want it to limit it to about 10 pages in the line

let's say:
page 1 to 10 and page 2 to 11 and so forth (like you would see on most sites)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code made it work for me :) (the '5' pieces still gotta be editted with the `$max_pages`

```
$max_pages = 10;
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i = max(1, $page - 5); $i <= min($page + 5, $total_pages); $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
echo "<a href='?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
```